# How to insert registry entries from a .reg file into 32-bit registry on 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, windows-registry, 32-bit

In 64-bit Windows (Vista/7), there's `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node` where all the 32-bit registry stuff is.  If I have a .reg file with some keys in it, how can I tell regedit to import it into the 32-bit registry (under `Wow6432Node`) rather than the 64-bit registry?

Even if I put the Wow6432 path into the registry keys in the .reg file, Windows "cleverly" ignores them and puts them in the main 64-bit registry.

Comment: Shame there's no apparent way to do this in the file itself as we won't always have control over how it's imported.

Comment: Don't use *regedit* for this. The `reg` command would have accepted your patch. But (maybe only meanwhile) actions like import and export across the 64-bit/32-bit boundary are well supported by the 64-bit `reg` tool. Please have a look on [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/1166312/391675).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to access the 32-bit registry exclusively using the 32 bit version of regedit.  Just import your `.reg` files using:

```
\Windows\syswow64\regedit.exe <REG_FILE.reg>
```

Comment: I think that's [much easier](http://superuser.com/a/1166312/391675) now.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using `reg import yourfile.reg` from a 32 bit executable or a batch file, and for some crazy reason you want the keys inside `yourfile.reg` to NOT be [redirected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to `Wow6432Node`, simply use the following syntax:

```
reg import yourfile.reg /reg:64
```

As easy as that.

Comment: I think this does **not answer the actual question**. Why not put the real answer first, adding the given supplement information later (or, even better, as a footnote)?

Answer (score 7):

The `reg` tool installed with the 64-bit version of Windows is aware of the registry virtualization technique. It has two new switches: `/reg:32` and `/reg:64`. If you want to apply a registry export from a 32-bit system to a 64-bit system, use the following command line:

```
reg import <CONF-APP-32.reg> /reg:32
```

The `reg` tool has a command line help that explains this in a very short form via `reg import /?`.

...you will find this also online (though a bit hard to google) for example:

- [MS-DOS reg command help](http://www.computerhope.com/reg.htm)
- [Reg - Edit Registry | Windows CMD | SS64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used below powershell commands to achieve it :

$RegFileName = ($_.RegFileName).trim()

reg import ".\$RegFileName" /reg:32