# Modifying registry from Cygwin not working

Tags: windows, windows-registry, cygwin

I'm trying to import a .reg file from Cygwin shell using

```
regedit.exe <registryfile>.reg
```

The dialogs pop up asking if I want to apply the registry changes, and I click yes, but no changes are made. If I run the exact same command through command prompt or by double-clicking the .reg file, the changes are applied correctly. What is it about Cygwin that would prevent regedit from working, and how can I go about modifying the registry from Cygwin?

I found out that my changes were being applied, but to some other dat file somewhere. When I just call regedit from Cygwin, I get a bunch of different keys than I would expect (for example all MSSQL keys are not there, but many other keys are)... Why does Cygwin open a different file?

Comment: What exactly is in this file?

Comment: Just key-value pairs that I want to change. I want to change the network configuration of a SQL Server instance.

Comment: you write "When I just call regedit from Cygwin, I get a bunch of different keys than I would expect"  What keys exactly? (that would help as it'd enable somebody else to try to reproduce what you see)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Parts of this answer assume that you are running a 64-bit version of Windows.</sup>

Windows has a few registry redirections in place, which make it appear different depending on the environment you are viewing it from. The most prominent are `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, which is loaded depending on the user profile in use, and the redirection for 32-bit processes - an example is the `Wow6432Node` key under `SOFTWARE`, which is what 32-bit applications see when they look for the `SOFTWARE` key.

Most likely, your Cygwin process is actually running under a different user and therefore launching `regedit` under this user. Otherwise, it could be due to running in 32-bit mode - without knowing which specific keys you are targeting, I cannot say for sure. There might also be other redirections I'm not aware of.

For more information on 32-bit (WOW64) registry redirection, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

There's a list of redirected keys [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For programmers, there are [flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can use to access a specific version of the registry. For the rest of us, run the appropriate version of Regedit - at least on Windows 7 and 8, `%SystemRoot%\regedit.exe` is always the 64-bit version and `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\regedit.exe` is always the 32-bit version.

Comment: I'm looking only at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE. Would this still impact which registry I see, and where can I learn more about the redirections?

Comment: I think it's because I'm using the 32 bit version of Cygwin, and my registry keys are 64 bit

Comment: @Samuel That's probably it. Trying to access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` from a 32-bit process will automatically give you `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` instead. You could try launching the 64-bit `regedit` directly - use the full path (`\Windows\regedit.exe`). You're basically trying for the opposite of [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/126148/117590).

Answer (score 0):

To import a file called /tmp/file.reg into the registry using Cygwin bash try:

```
reg=/tmp/file.reg
unix2dos $reg
cmd /c "%SystemRoot%\regedit.exe \s `cygpath -w $reg`"
```